# Get reference to Page from UserControl

Tags: windows-8, controls

I think the titel says it all: I have a UserControl inside my Page. How can I get a reference to the Page where the UserControl is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the current Page with

```
(Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as Page
```